# How to compose images in JAVA using control points?

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I want to achieve the goal that having two images in JAVA, having defined control points for both of them, I will be able to overlap and compose a final image based on these control points.

This means that each control point on ONE image has a direct relationship with a control point on the second, so that when composing the two images they will match perfectly.

An example of this usage could be for example wearing a person with different clothes (the shirt has control points which match control points on the body) by overlapping and redimensioning.

The question is that the normal redimension methods redimensionate images in a "proportionate" way, this means only width and height. I'd like to create some control points on an image in such a way:

[image]

So that I can redimension the image just based on those control points.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at **nonrigid image deformation** techniques, sometimes referred to as image **morphing** or image **warping**. Be aware that they require a good deal of mathematics to understand, and numerical software components (esp. a good linear solver) to be implemented.

A classic method for control-point-based image deformation is the [Thin Plate Spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_plate_spline). I find the [original paper](http://www.engineering.uiowa.edu/~aip/papers/bookstein-89.pdf) more helpful for implementation than the Wikipedia entry.

[This](http://davis.wpi.edu/~matt/courses/morph/2d.htm) is a page with some other techniques.

Comment: would you recommend me to give a look at Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) API? I am asking this because it seems that they have stopped any developing of it since 2007.

Comment: I'm doing image processing in C++ and Python only, so, unfortunately, I don't know many Java APIs. The only one I am aware of is ImageJ, http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/ . Its quite large, so maybe you find something helpful.